# Capistrano 3 symlink nginx.conf asks for password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, symlink, capistrano3, sudoers

I'm trying to create a symlink to the nginx conf file from my `current_path`.

This is in my cap task:

```
on roles(:app) do
    execute :sudo, :ln, "-nfs", "#{fetch(:current_path)}/config/nginx_#{fetch(:stage)}.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{fetch(:application)}"
end
```

In my server's `sudoers` I have:

```
Cmnd_Alias LNFROMCURR    = /bin/ln -nfs /home/deployer/app_name/current/* /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*

deployer  ALL=NOPASSWD: LNFROMCURR
```

Yet during deployment capistrano asks me for password for sudo. I have even tried making the sudden rule more generic to no avail.

Comment: Can you post your complete `sudoers` file and are you sure you have `set :pty, true` in your `deploy.rb`?